# create a Generic List

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

```
public class Sortieralgorithmen<T extends Comparable <T>>
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
         UserInput read = new UserInput();
         ArrayList<Integer> list = read.type(muster, type, length, rounds);
         ArrayList<T> list = read.type(muster, type, length, rounds);
    }
 }
```

Why is the first working and the second is not?

`type` is a method in the class `UserInput`. There I will fill the Array.

Answer (score 2):

Your class has a type parameter `T`, but your `main` is a static method.

Just like non-static fields the type parameter `T` is only accessible in non-static methods (as there is no instance to "take" the type `T` from in static methods).